# Replace main NSManagedObjectContext with the MOC from background thread rather than merge

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

When using a background thread to update Core Data, is there a way to replace the main`NSManagedObjectContext` with the updated context from the background thread rather than calling`mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`?

I don't want to merge the two. I just want the updated context to replace the main context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was to switch back to the main context before the background context saves

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(deletemainmoc) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

and delete all the objects. then when it switches back to the background thread it saves and then you can merge into a clean context.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could just save the context on the background thread, and then  dispose of the context on the main thread and create a brand new one on the main thread.

Comment: when i do save the context on the background thread it doesn't update the fetchedresultscontroller-backed uitableview.

Comment: Thanks! What I did instead was wipe the context on the main thread just before saving the background. then i merged the two.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this. Managed objects are associated with a MOC; you can't just change the "main" MOC and expect everything in your app to notice; you'll have to make all your objects that reference "main" MOs point to MOs from the new MOC.

`-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` (mostly) works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks. When i use merge it creates duplicate entries i.e. puts the two contexts together. Is there a way to merge where only the new MOC objects are kept?

Comment: Er, don't create duplicate objects?

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out for myself eventually. Answer below. Maybe this isn't the most elegant way but it works for now.